# Почему не удается подписать файл с использованием pfx сертификата?

Tags: windows, цифровая-подпись

Установлена Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3. Сертификат в виде pfx-файла получен с использованием утилиты pvk2pfx из Windows SDK для Windows Vista. Если подписывать файл командой

```
> signtool sign /f ManufacturerSignature.pfx /p password software.exe
```

выводится ошибка

*SignTool Error: File not found: ManufacturerSignature.pfx*

хотя pfx-файл заведомо находится в папке исполнения и права на чтения для пользователя есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, ошибка исправляется сменой имени pfx-файла. Команда

```
> signtool sign /f cert.pfx /p password software.exe
```

подписывает файл успешно.